# Maxmind Free GeopIP Encoding Issues in Latest CSV

Tags: geolocation, location, geoip, maxmind

While Going trough the maxmind free geopip2 i encounterd records as follows when i was figuring which IP belongs to India and as per Country Record India has geoname_id as 1269750

[image]

> **geoname_id**,locale_code,continent_code,continent_name,country_iso_code,country_name,subdivision_1_iso_code,subdivision_1_name,subdivision_2_iso_code,subdivision_2_name,city_name,metro_code,time_zone,is_in_european_union
>   **1864529**,en,AS,Asia,JP,**Japan**,13,Tokyo,,,Chiyoda-ku,,Asia/Tokyo,0
>
> Similarly while accessing the Location Block CSV
>
> network,**geoname_id**,network,geoname_id,registered_country_geoname_id,represented_country_geoname_id,is_anonymous_proxy,is_satellite_provider,postal_code,latitude,longitude,accuracy_radius,represented_country_geoname_id,is_anonymous_proxy,is_satellite_provider,postal_code,latitude,longitude,accuracy_radius
>
> 2001:df0:299::/48,**1864529,1269750**,,0,0,102-0071,35.6966,139.7444,200
>   2001:df0:2a3::/48,**1864529,1269750**,,0,0,102-0071,35.6966,139.7444,200

So Why does Japan geoname_id **1864529** has registered_country_geoname_id as India **1269750**

As per maxmind :

```
**registered_country_geoname_id**:  The registered country is the country in which the ISP has registered the network. This column contains a unique identifier for the network's registered country as specified by GeoNames. This ID can be used to look up the location information in the Location file.
```

Can any one explain what is significance of registered_country_geoname_id